# lsof gives "information error: Cannot allocate memory" in iOS

Tags: ios, runtime-error, out-of-memory, jailbreak, lsof

My intent is to check for TCP and UDP being opened by a specific process.

`lsof -p $1 | grep -E "TCP|UDP"` *(this works well on Mac OS)*

I installed **lsof binary** on a **jailbroken** iPad, from cydia. When i execute lsof on iOS device *(terminal)*, it just gives me errors saying: `information error: Cannot allocate memory`

I tried compiling lsof for iOS (arm) from various *[sources](https://github.com/u35tpus/iosrep/)* but the *make* fails.

Also tried to install *[.deb](http://coredev.nl/cydia/dists/iphone/main/binary-iphoneos-arm/)* on the iPad, using `dpkg -i` but it gave errors saying that ruby and other dependencies are not found.

Would be great if I could get help in getting lsof to function properly on iOS. Or a working alternative for lsof. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### update

I copy the file from my old device and upload it to GitHub [here](https://github.com/sunkehappy/iOS-reverse-engineering-tools-backup).

---

I encounter the same problem. I solved it by this:

1. Download [lsof-arm7-iOS4.2](http://pupil.io8.org/pub/iphone/misc/lsof/lsof-arm7-iOS4.2).
2. Backup the old lsof to lsof-backup.
3. Copy the downloaded the lsof-arm7-iOS4.2 to iDevice.
4. Rename the lsof-arm7-iOS4.2 to lsof
5. Then `chmod +x lsof`

Reference:

http://modmyi.com/forums/native-iphone-ipod-touch-app-discussion/721184-lsof-problem.html

Comment: +1 This solution still works (and is still necessary) on iOS 7.0.

Comment: This link does not work anymore. Does anyone have a saved file?

Comment: On iOS 9 this binary gives `Killed: 9` mesage. =(

Comment: As noted in the edit at the top of this answer, the file can be found here: https://github.com/sunkehappy/iOS-reverse-engineering-tools-backup/blob/master/lsof-arm7-iOS4.2 (Just used it successfully 2022-08-08)